# Windows 7 Start Menu Search is not indexing?

Tags: windows, windows-search

I upgraded my Vista Ultimate to Win 7 Professional.

I have configured all the search indexing settings, however search box in the start menu does not bring any result at all in the indexed folders. It says a few thousands of files are indexed but nothing appears in start menu search.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the Windows Search service running?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the index?

Comment: This Microsoft forum post may help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/a7e6c315-bfa6-4e7d-888d-a2c7d8de560c.